# Dynamic tickValues on time.scale in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I built a graph in D3, to show spending based on date time and amount of spending, but I can't dynamically set `tickValues()` on my time.scale to show only ticks for data points.

My scale set up is:

```
   var dateScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(newData, function(d) { return d.Date; }))
        .range([padding, width - padding]);

    var amountScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(newData, function(d) { return d.Amount; })])
        .range([window.height - padding, padding]);

    // Define date Axis
    var dateAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(dateScale)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d %m'))
        .tickSize(100 - height)
        .orient("bottom");

    // Draw date Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr({
            "class": "axis date-axis",
            "transform": "translate(" + [0, height -padding] + ")"
        }).call(dateAxis);

    // Define amount Axis
    var amountAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(amountScale)
        .tickSize(1)
        .orient("left");

    // Draw amount Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr({
            "class": "axis amount-axis",
            "transform": "translate(" + padding + ",0)"
        }).call(amountAxis);
```

I've tried to set
`dateAxis.tickValues(d3.extent(newData, function(d) { return d.Date; }))`
but this only returns min and max value for date axis.
Also `tickValues()` doesn't accept `newData` itself - what else I can try here?

I want to achieve this:
[image]
to have only ticks highlighted, associated with corresponding data.

Comment: Just remove `d3.extent()` and use `map` instead, i.e. `dateAxis.tickValues(newData.map(function(d) { return d.Date; }))`.

Comment: Yup - that's what I've ended up with - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with creating new array of all date points out of my data, to pass it to `tickValues()` method. My code now is:

```
var newData = toArray(uniqueBy(data, function(x){return x.Date;}, function(x, y){ x.Amount += y.Amount; return x; }));

    // Create array of data date points
    var tickValues = newData.map(function(d){return d.Date;});

    // Sorting data ascending
    newData = newData.sort(sortByDateAscending);

    var dateScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(d3.extent(newData, function(d) { return d.Date; }))
        .range([padding, width - padding]);

    var amountScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(newData, function(d) { return d.Amount; })])
        .range([window.height - padding, padding]);

    // Define date Axis
    var dateAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(dateScale)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d %m %Y'))
        .tickValues(tickValues)
        .orient("bottom");
```

So now whole graph looks as:
[image]

I found this [SO (@AmeliaBR) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416316/how-do-we-change-the-tick-values-generated-by-a-linear-scale-in-a-d3-js-line-plo) explaining `tickValues()` function, and [here is documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) for it too.